# Unable to search for a file through windows 7start button

Tags: windows, windows-7

If I search for the file in file window, I am able to find it, but why I am not able to search through start button of windows 7? Please see the below image

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Right Click on start menu > Properties >

In the start menu tab > Customise.

Scroll down till you can customise your search preferences!

Comment: I tried it now after your answer, but still not able to search for the required file, anyway thank you for giving the answer